# Timeit module - Passing objects to setup?

Tags: python, time, timeit

I am trying to use the timeit module to time the speed of an algorithm that analyzes data.

The problem is that I have to do run some setup code in order to run this algorithm. Specifically, I have to load some documents from a database, and turn it into matrix representation.

The timeit module does not seem to allow me to pass in the matrix object, and instead forces me to set this up all over again in the setup parameter. Unfortunately this means that the running time of my algorithm is fuzzed by the running time of pre-processing.

Is there some way to pass in objects that were created already, to timeit in the setup parameter? Otherwise, how can I deal with situations where the setup code takes a nontrivial amount of time, and I don't want that to fuzz the code block I actually am trying to test?

Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running time of your algorithm is **not fuzzed** by the running time of pre-processing. This can be proved as: Suppose I declare a `list` in `__main__` module and run `timeit` to find index of some item in this `list`. But I need to pass the `list` to `timeit` too. The `list` passing is sort of pre-processing. Time returned by `timeit` shows **0.26 sec** (see below code). Now if `timeit` would have calculated the pre-processing time (importing list from `__main__`) too, then the result would have been almost 1.1 sec, because importing `list` from `__main__` requires **0.84 sec** for 1000000 iterations (see below code). What `timeit` does is it imports `list` from `__main__` only once and then calculates time required by the algorithm for given number of iterations.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> lst = range(10)
>>> timeit.timeit('lst.index(9)', 'from __main__ import lst', number = 1000000)
0.2645089626312256
>>> timeit.timeit('from __main__ import lst', number = 1000000)
0.8406829833984375
```

Comment: @user2142580: you could even compare it directly: `min(timeit.repeat(partial(lst.index, 9)))` (here there is no `setup` step but the result should be similar).

Comment: So, let's say I want to run this experiment 5 times. I'm doing timeit.Timer(function_call_string, setup=setup).repeat(5, 1)). Would this call setup 5 times? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The time it takes to run the setup code doesn't affect the `timeit` module's timing calculations.

You should be able to pass your matrix into the setup parameter using import, eg

`"from __main__ import mymatrix"`